# Overwrite the LoginWidget and Set DestinationPageUrl dynamically in Sitefinity

Tags: dynamic, authentication, widget, overwrite, sitefinity

I want to add some custom code during the login function, in particular i want to redirect the user after login to the previous page.

For example: i'm on page A , i want to download something from this page, but i'm not authorized. Then pops a popup with link to the login page. After successful login i'm back on page A.

For this purpose i want to overwrite the LoginWidged and to set value to"this.DestinationPageUrl" dynamically.

I read about similar issues [here](http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/developing-with-sitefinity-/overwrite-the-login-function-to-add-custom-code)  and  [here](http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/stanislav-velikovs-blog/2012/01/23/how_to_add_additional_logic_into_sitefinity_built_in_widgets), but there isn't an example how to overwrite this LoginWidget class.

I create CustomLoginControl.cs file in my project and register as a new custom control, but after rendering it on the page, it didn't work. Login button does not make nothing. I'm not sure what exactly have to do and which of methods have to overwrite.

```
namespace SitefinityWebApp.UserControls
{
    public class CustomLoginControl : Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.PublicControls.LoginWidget
    {
        protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            this.DestinationPageUrl = "http://previousPage.com";

            base.Render(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you give me an example  how to overwrite this class to work properly.

Version: Sitefinity 5.0, Claims-based authentication

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar but instead of overriding the login control you can subscribe and capture the [UnauthorizedAccess event](http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/developers-guide/deep-dive/sitefinity-event-system/list-of-events/pages-events), send the user to your login page with your redirect page as a query string parameter. You'll need to add a Global.asax / Global.asax.cs file to your project, then add this to the Application_Start function:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bootstrapper.Initialized += BootstrapperInitialized;            
}
```

Then add these two functions:

```
private void BootstrapperInitialized(object sender, ExecutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Bootstrapped")
    {
        EventHub.Subscribe<IUnauthorizedPageAccessEvent>(OnUnauthorizedAccess);
    }
}

private void OnUnauthorizedAccess(IUnauthorizedPageAccessEvent unauthorizedEvent)
{
    var manager = ConfigManager.GetManager();
    string loginPage = manager.GetSection<ProjectConfig>().DefaultSite.FrontEndLoginPageUrl;

    var redirectParam = unauthorizedEvent.RedirectUrl.Replace(string.Format("{0}?ReturnUrl=", loginPage), string.Empty);

    var escaped = Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectParam);

    unauthorizedEvent.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(string.Format("{0}?ReturnUrl={1}", loginPage, escaped));
}
```

You will also need to set your default front end login page in the settings under Administration -> Settings -> Advanced -> Project -> DefaultSite and the FrontEndLoginPageUrl setting.

This works for me on a 6.3 site, not sure if this is available in Sitefinity 5 or not.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately i don't have access to "EventHub"and to "IUnauthorizedPageAccessEvent".
In which assembly are these placed? 
`Telerik.Sitefinity.Services.EventHub.Subscribe`

Services here don't have any  "EventHub" type or namespace.

Comment: Hi Atanas, what version of Sitefinity are you using, 5.0?